# EF Code First computing Modified and Created properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

Given the following class, is there a way to calculate the Created and Modified properties of an entity automatically in EF Code first?

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Can it be done by Attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a repository pattern for this purpose in EF.

A POCO might implement

```
public interface IFQuickAudit {
    Nullable<DateTimeOffset> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    Nullable<long> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    Nullable<DateTimeOffset> ChangedOn { get; set; }
    Nullable<long> ChangedBy { get; set; }
}
```

if it does the base respository checks this during Add or CHange methods
and sets the values

```
public class RepositoryBase<TPoco>
//...
public virtual OperationResult Add(TPoco poco)
var entityQA = poco as IFQuickAudit;
        if (entityQA != null) {
             entityQA .CreatedBy = userId;
             entityQA .CreatedOn = when;
        }

// checks...
Context.Set<TPoco>().Add(poco);

// similar for Chnage routine
```

Comment: Thanks - I have implemented this in the base repository. I was hoping that there might be a way to do it using attributes, but this works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193958.aspx:

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

> You can use database generated on byte or timestamp columns when code first is generating
>   the database, otherwise you should only use this when pointing to
>   existing databases because code first won't be able to determine the
>   formula for the computed column.

I've never tried it but it looks like it'll work and I'm glad to have learned this too.

Comment: actually this might only be 1/2 an answer bec I don't know how EF would know that Created only gets set the first time and Modified gets updated every time...

Comment: Thanks, but I think this only works for `byte[]` times shich are marked with the `TimestampAttribute`. In my understanding The `TimeStamp` and `DateTime` are 2 different things.

Comment: hmm, but the example i pasted in was from the docs too and that's a DateTime... oh wel

Comment: Yeah, that doco is for when you have a rule defined in the DB which will update that field. Thanks though.